# Effect of doping in Superconductor

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, quantum-chemistry

Doping an element (for example element substitution) could be lower down the critical temperature of superconductor, but i don't know the mechanism behind this, is it because  more bosons need to freeze out in order to achieve the zero resistance? if so, is there a formula or equation relating the doping concentration and critical temp? thanks!

Comment: In conventional Superconductors, as far as I know, Only magnetic elements has effect on Tc. since magnetic moment interacts on electron spins and break cooper pairs..

Comment: I'm not an expert on high-Tc superconductivity, so I'll not venture in a complete answer. The effect of the doping is related to the chemistry property of the materials sometimes. For instance, many cuprates are in fact quasi-layered materials of Cu-O planes. When doping, you play with the distance between the different layers, which result in a change of the critical temperature for instance. As @pan91 said, doping a conventional superconductor should not alter drastically the critical temperature, until the impurities are magnetic.

Comment: So in short to understand the doping you need to understand the materials structure, and chemistry.

Comment: @pan91,so as impurities (magnetic elements) concentration increases, more copper pair will break leading to decrease the critical temperature?

Comment: @FraSchelle so distance between the layers is directly proportional to critical temp?

Comment: I would not say *directly proportional* by it's related for sure, at least for quasi-2D layered materials. I'm not sure the reason is completely clear for everyone. At least for me it's not, so please do not ask me to explain why ? ;-)

Comment: @Raldenors, I think so :)